# Clustering multivariate binary data

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I want to use a clustering algorithm which can catch the following within a multivariate binary dataset. In the sample below, since class 1 and 2 appear twice within column A and B they will form a cluster. The same will be for class 5 and 6. Class 3 and 4 will belong to a cluster which is located closer to class 1 and 2 since column B has class 1 to 4.
Is hierarchical clustering an appropriate technique to display this kind of relationship?

The data are as follow:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| class1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| class2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| class3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| class4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| class5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| class6 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, hierarchical clustering will be appropriate for this. There are many different methods you can use (agglomerative etc.) which I won't go into.

The way to think about this is by looking at the distance between rows.

- Class 1 and 2 get grouped together because the distance between their rows is zero. (They have the same elements).
- Class 5 and 6 get grouped together for the same reason.
- Class 3 and 4 get grouped together for the same reason.
- Cluster 3&4 is closer to 1&2 than 5&6 because the distance between the rows is smaller.
- For example, if our distance metric is just the sum of row-wise differences then the distance from 1&2 to 3&4 is 1 while the distance from 5&6 to 3&4 is 3.

So the two choices you need to make are:

1. Which clustering algorithm to use.
2. What distance metric to use.

Comment: thank you, it helps. Do you know if it is possible to express the probability that  a class will be selected with another class? FYI, I use Scipy with Pyhton to do this.